# SAS, converting numbers, from character format to numeric format, keeping all leading zeros, but length of numbers is NOT uniform

Tags: sas, type-conversion, leading-zero

I'm working in SAS EG and I'm trying to convert a column that's in character format to numeric format, EXACTLY as they appear in their character format.  The numbers vary in length and some have one or two leading zeros.

If I do it one way, it gets rid of all leading zeros.  Another way I tried, it adds leading zeros to the point that it's as long as the longest number in the column, e.g., a 9-digit number with one leading zero now has four leading zeros because the longest number in the column is 12 digits. (I hope this description makes sense).

I'm working in SAS EG.  When I run proc contents, it tells me my existing variable is a character variable of length 26.  It is blank for both 'format' and 'informat.'

I need to convert it so that a new column is a numeric variable, with length 8, and 'F12.' for 'format' and 'BEST12.' for 'informat,' as I plan to use it to match two data sets.

I created the following test data set in 'regular' SAS, but I'm not sure if fully recreates the issue I'm working on in SAS EG:

```
data have;
input mrn $1-12;
cards;
118283586928
003875807
038087875
0385709873
0038576830
;
run;
```

As you can see, I have one number that's 12 digits long (no leading zeros); two that are 9 digits (with one or two leading zeros); and two that are 10 digits (with one or two leading zeros).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You say "I plan to use it (the char value converted to number value) to match two data sets".  The number format is not considered when matching numeric values, so you probably can pull yourself out of this rabbit hole.

Comment: In the table with the character version of the values are the leading zeros significant? That is would `'00012'` and `'12'` mean two different cases?

Comment: Leading zeros have no meaning for numbers, they're just for display, what is the underlying issue? Where did you get this data from originally?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to have different formats in the same column in SAS.  The only way to keep them looking exactly as they do while in the same column is to keep them as text.  If you need to do calculations on them I'd suggest just creating a 2nd column with their numeric values.

Leading zeros can be added to numbers using the z. format.

https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000205244.htm

Answer (score 1):

You cannot store 26 digit strings exactly as a number in SAS.  SAS stores numbers as floating point values.  You can use the CONSTANT() function to see the end of the contiguous integers that can be stored exactly.

```
73    data _null_;
74     x=constant('exactint');
75     put x= comma30.;
76    run;

x=9,007,199,254,740,992
```

So if you actually have values longer than 15 digits in the character variable you will not be able to convert them to numbers.

But if they are only 12 digits long then just convert the strings into numbers and compare the numbers.

```
proc sql;
  create table want as 
    select * 
    from a, b
    where a.mrn = input(b.mrn_string,32.)
  ;
quit;
```